# how to add cell when scroll down initially in a table view in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to make a calendar app and current date should be on the top of a tableview ,previous dates appear when scroll down and next date appear on scroll up.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is fill your table view completely first.  Then you want to statically scroll the table view to a location in the middle of the table using

```
-(void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

See link below

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

You might choose to do this within the

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

routine

Answer (score 0):

There's a `property` `contentOffset` of `UITableView` set it as per your requirement.

```
[yourTableViewObject setContentOffset:CGPointMake:(x,y)];
```

here, x would be 0 and y would be the position you want to off the table from its current.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an array of object and one of the fields on your object is dateCreated, you could do something like this to sort your data before displaying it.

```
   NSSortDescriptor * descDate = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:NO];
   [dataArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descDate, nil]];
```